# Stacking HTML elements at the bottom of a container

Tags: html, css

I have a div (with a fixed width) that has 2 image elements as children.

Each image is the same width as the div so the images are placed not on the same row ([see  screenshot](http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/1560/screenshot1dm.png)) .

This is great, but I want the images to displayed the same way (one on top of the other) but at the bottom of the div.

I'm able to achieve such behavior in some browsers using:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
```

on the div css.

Is there a nicer way to achieve that?

Here is the code I used for the example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.container {background:url(http://img01.imagefra.me/img/img01/1/11/10/f_dwr8biwm_3ed594d.png) no-repeat;height:116px;
width:33px}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://img01.imagefra.me/img/img01/1/11/10/f_ei8p1qf6om_0e5c35c.png" width="33px">
    <img src="http://img01.imagefra.me/img/img01/1/11/10/f_ei8p1qf6om_0e5c35c.png" width="33px">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the container `position:relative;` and set the images to `position:absolute; bottom:0;`

However, this will not stack the images.  They will overlay each other.  If you need them stacked, the easiest (dynamic) way is to wrap the images with another container (like a `div`), and then set the styles on *it*.  For example...

Markup:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="innerContainer">
    <img src="http://img01.imagefra.me/img/img01/1/11/10/f_ei8p1qf6om_0e5c35c.png" width="33px" /> 
    <img src="http://img01.imagefra.me/img/img01/1/11/10/f_ei8p1qf6om_0e5c35c.png" width="33px" />
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  background:url(http://img01.imagefra.me/img/img01/1/11/10/f_dwr8biwm_3ed594d.png) no-repeat;
  height:116px;
  width:33px;
  position:relative;
}

.container .innerContainer {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
 }
```

Comment: This causes both images to be positioned at the bottom (the second one hiding the first).  I want them to be stacked - the forst one at the bottom, the next one just above it.

Comment: Then add `style="bottom:33px;"` to the first `IMG` element.

Comment: If hard-coding that in there is not your thing, you will have to wrap the images with an "inner container" element and set *it* to have the absolute position and bottom:0

Comment: Thanks Josh - the inner container is just what I needed. I think it merits editing the answer (so I can accept it).

Comment: @Danny I have updated the answer.  I am glad you have resolved the problem.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, I wouldn't mind playing the game when you get it finished ;)

Answer (score 2):

The solution: Add an innner div and set its position to bottom:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.container {background:url(http://img01.imagefra.me/img/img01/1/11/10/f_dwr8biwm_3ed594d.png) no-repeat;height:116px;position:relative;
width:33px;}
.inner {position:absolute;bottom:0px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container"><div class="inner">
<img src="http://img01.imagefra.me/img/img01/1/11/10/f_ei8p1qf6om_0e5c35c.png" width="33px">
<img src="http://img01.imagefra.me/img/img01/1/11/10/f_ei8p1qf6om_0e5c35c.png" width="33px">
</div></div>
</body>
```

Thanks to Josh for suggesting this.